# Laravel merge 2 queries into one

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I am trying to merge query into one, is there's anyway to avoid if statement and merge the query into one query?

Each `organization` has different `specialties`, which works great in the first query, i wanted to get all the `specialties` from the `specialties` table which is second query and avoid those specialties which are already define in `organization`, so far i try the below queries it worked great, however when there's no `organization` it return an error, any help would be highly appreciated.

```
$specialityOrg = Organization::where('id', $id)->first()->specialties()->get()->map(fn($post) => [
            'id' => $post->id,
            'active' => $post->active,
            'name' => $post->name
        ]);
        if ($specialityOrg->isNotEmpty()) {
            $specialityAll = Speciality::root()->where('name', '!=', $specialityOrg[0]['name'])->get()->map(fn($post) => [
                'id' => $post->id,
                'active' => $post->active,
                'name' => $post->name
            ]);
        }

        $speciality = collect()->merge($specialityOrg)->merge($specialityAll);

        return view('organizations.speciality', compact('speciality'));
```

Comment: It would be an anti pattern to merge the query into one as it is two different models. What is the error with the code you have now? I would not call what you have now pretty or optimal but in most cases it would do the trick. I would guess you can just null coalescent the property not certain if there and solve the error. ->merge($specialityAll ?? collect([]));

Comment: @mrhn you are right. issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by altering your approach: start by retrieving all specialties and then filter out the ones associated with the organization in a single query.

```
$specialityAll = Speciality::root()
    ->whereNotIn('name', function($query) use ($id) {
        $query->select('name')
            ->from('specialties')
            ->where('organization_id', $id);
    })->get()
   ->map(function($post) {
        return [
            'id'     => $post->id,
            'active' => $post->active,
            'name'   => $post->name
        ];
    });
```